# How to make a method for whenever a user navigates to a page in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin.Forms App, I want a method to only be triggered when an Android user goes to a certain page in my application.  I know that there is an OnCreate() for the MainActivity.cs, but is there something like this for when a user navigates to a specified page in my Shared Project?

So the method would not be carried out when the app is opened, but when the user of the Android app navigates to a certain page.

Thank you!

Comment: use the Page OnAppearing method

Comment: Will this work when you are in the Xamarin.Android project referencing to a page in the Shared project?

Comment: it will get fired whenever the page appears.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... just to be clear, I am defining this in the MainActivity.cs class of the Xamarin.Android project and referencing to a page in the shared project.  I apologize, I am a beginner to all of this... is it possible to post this as an answer and show me an example?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're doing.  "defining this in the MainActivity.cs class of the Xamarin.Android project and referencing to a page in the shared project" does not sound like standard Forms project.  It would help if you posted your actual code

Comment: typically `MainActivity` will have a line like `LoadApplication (new App ());` which passes control to the Forms App class in your shared project, which then assigns the initial UI page.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: I'm actually working with push notifications (so the set-up is different for Android and iOS, so I have to write a lot of native code, but there are still pages and UI elements in the shared code. I don't really think that posting the code will help in my case, as this is more of a question on how to approach this concept

Comment: @Jason, yes there is a line that says LoadApplication (new App()); in the MainActivity, which starts the user off in the MainPage.  I would like for that to be there in the OnCreate of course, but have a method that happens when the user navigates to a specific page other than the MainPage that is supposed to be displayed OnCreate. So not dealing with what the initial page is, but working with the user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all Xamarin Forms pages have an `OnAppearing` method that will be called when the page displays

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
      // call your method here
    }
}
```

you can then use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send a message from the page to your `MainActivity`

in `MainActivity`

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPage>(this, "MyPageAppearing", (sender) =>
{
    // Do something whenever the message is received
});
```

and in your page's `OnAppearing`

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MyPage>(this, "MyPageAppearing");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However, what I am trying to do is have some sort of method in the MainActivity that will happen whenever a page in the shared project appears.  I apologize if it is unclear or oncommon what I am trying to do, I would be happy to answer any questions.

Comment: you can use MessagingCenter to send a message from OnAppearing to your MainActivity when the page appears.

Comment: Yeah that could work! Thank you.  Would it also be possible to write a line of code inside the OnAppearing to call to a method in the MainActivity class (after checking with a Device.RuntimePlatform that the device is an android device)?

Comment: No.  Avoid tightly coupling code together that way, use MessagingCenter to do it instead.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Comment: @ums2026 I'm genuinely curious as to why you would even _need_ this function in the first place. Very strange.

Comment: @Jason, when I try out this code I am getting all sorts of "MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPage> doesn't exist kind of stuff... is there some package I need to install or anything like that?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate namespaces referenced for Forms and your page class?

Comment: Actually, now I am having an error.  It only allows for me to do this INSIDE of another method... but then the method is never getting called to and nothing is happening because of that. I don't want to put it in OnCreate() because I don't want it to be called every time the app is launched.  It kind of goes in a loop in that sense - I want it to go when there is navigation, and for that I need to write that inside a method for that.

Comment: Please take the time to read the docs - calling Subscribe doesn't actually execute the method, it just registers a listener for that message.  When the message is actually received it will execute the code.  If you want to stop listening for that message, call Unsubscribe